# Scala type members do not compile

Tags: scala, type-members

I wrote the following simple example and expected it to be compiled fine:

```
abstract class TestObject extends App{
  type Type

  def method[F[_]](ft: F[Type], t: Test[F]{
    type Type = TestObject#Type
  }) = t.doSomeAction(ft) //ERROR
}

trait Test[F[_]]{
  type Type
  def doSomeAction(t: F[Type]) = println(t)
}
```

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/ykV42O)

But the compiler prints the following error message:

```
Error:(8, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : ft.type (with underlying type F[TestObject.this.Type])
 required: F[t.Type]
    (which expands to)  F[TestObject#Type]
Note: TestObject.this.Type <: t.Type, but type F is invariant in type _.
You may wish to define _ as +_ instead. (SLS 4.5)
  }) = t.doSomeAction(ft)
```

I do not really understand it since `Test#Type = TestObject#Type`.

Comment: Doesn't the error message explain the problem and give the solution? What happens if you do what it suggests?

Comment: @Tim In case `TestObject#Type <: Test#Type`, but not the same one yes it would make sense. But I declared them to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that `TestObject#Type` captures an existential type which is not what you want. you want to ensure that the `Type` of *specific* instances line up. you can do this like this:

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/wpI8iGg/0

or more commonly with the Aux-Pattern

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/wpI8iGg/1

Comment: Btw, is that `Aux` similar to `shapeless` one?

Comment: so the `Aux` thing is widely used in shapeless but it is not exclusively a shapeless thing. it is often used exactly like here to make types line up between 2 different things. e.g. `def foo[T, H <: HList](t:T)(implicit Generic.Aux[T,H])` if you call this like `foo((1, "asdf"))` the scala compiler will be able to calculate `H` because of the implicit restriction there, subsequently binding `H` to `Int :: String :: HNil` and you'll be able to use that type from there